# How to search for a specific string in List of string array

Tags: c#, arrays, string, list, linq

How to search for a specific string in List of string array if I have List like this:

```
adjustmentJSON.columns = new List<string[]>
{
    new[] {"A|green"}, new[] {"B|green"}, new[] {"A|green"},
    new[] {"DD|green"}, new[] {"|green"}, new[] {"|green"}, new[] {"NN|red"}
};
```

---

```
var skipValue = 0;
var TOTALDYNAMICSECTIONS = 5;

var categorizationByBenefitHeader = adjustmentJSON.columns
    .Skip(skipValue)
    .Take(TOTALDYNAMICSECTIONS)
    .Where(b => adjustmentJSON.columns.Contains(new[] { "green" }))
    .ToList();
```

I want to get:

```
["A|green","B|green","A|green","DD|green","|green"]
```

Comment: What is the type of input data? What does `If skipValue = 0,TOTALDYNAMICSECTIONS =4` mean?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I mean I have a list of arrays of strings, so I loop, searching the first 5 items, then the second 5 items and so on because some business logic

Comment: Do you really want to `Skip` and `Take` *before* you filter the results?

Comment: @RufusL yeah,I want to do this

Comment: Ok, just checking. So the results may be fewer than `TOTALDYNAMICSECTIONS`

Comment: What if some of the arrays have more than one value? And what if that other value doesn't contain the word "green"?

Comment: @RufusL every array should contain a string value

Comment: Yes, but what if they contain *more than one* string value? Or are you saying that they won't?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`SelectMany`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=netcore-3.1) to flatten the nested collections:

```
var categorizationByBenefitHeader = adjustmentJSON.columns
     .SelectMany(arr => arr)
     .Where(s => s.Contains("green"))
     .Skip(skipValue)
     .Take(TOTALDYNAMICSECTIONS)
     .ToList();
```